# Assigning dict to class variable converts it to tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I've been using python for a while and I've never run into this.

I am passing a `dict` to a class and assigning it to a class variable like so.

```
class Validator(ABC):
    def __init__(self, available_messages, rule_list: dict, data) -> None:
        self.available_messages = available_messages,
        self.rule_list: dict = rule_list,      
        self.data = data
        self.messages = []
        self.validate()
```

If I print the type of `rule_list` prior to assigning it to `self.rule_list` I get `<class 'dict'>`. Immedietly after assignment, I get `<class 'tuple'>`.

I want to keep `rule_list` as a dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the comma at the end of the Line, making it a tuple

Comment: I think we noticed it at the same time, can't believe I missed it! I'll accept your answer when the waiting period expires.

Comment: Can you consider to accept my answer? Would give me some reputation

Comment: Thank you.  Another Python weirdness...  I would prefer an exception when my code has a trailing comma but...  anyhoooo

Answer (score 0):

Wow...... I can't believe I missed this, I think I've been writing too much JS lately.

I placed commas after each variable assignment in my constructor.